# how to keep directory structure with #include In cmake?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Having problems setting up a project to keep directory structure with cmake.

Project structure I want to keep:

```
Project
|-libA
|   |-fileA.h
|   |-fileA.cpp
|   |-CMakeLists.txt
|-include
|   |-fileI.h
|-program1
|   |-main.cpp
|   |-CMakeLists.txt
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

source code include example:

```
#include "libA/fileA.h"
```

This doesn't work. **Cmake can't find "libA/fileA.h"**, it will only work if I create a following directory structure:

```
Project
|-libA
|   |-libA (directory)
|       |-fileA.h
|       |-fileA.cpp
|   |-CMakeLists.txt
|-include
|   |-fileI.h
|-program1
|   |-main.cpp
|   |-CMakeLists.txt
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

What can I do to keep the project structure as shown in the first example and to keep directory name in source files? (eg #include "libA/fileA.h")

Project cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(A)
include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(program1)
```

libA cmake:

```
set(LIBA_SRC libA/fileA.cpp)
add_library(libA SHARED ${LIBA_SRC})
```

Program1 cmake:

```
set (PROGRAM1_SRC main.cpp)
add_executable (program1 ${PROGRAM_SRC})
target_link_libraries (program1 libA)
target_include_directories (program1 PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libA)
```

Comment: What about simply changing `target_include_directories (program1 PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libA)` to `target_include_directories (program1 PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})`?

Comment: @super Yes that worked! Thanks for your tip. Make it an answer and I will accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the include directory in program1 to

```
target_include_directories (program1 PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

it will search from your source directory, so "libA/fileA.h" will find it's target.